# Слетела локализация. Выбор знаков

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

И не только тут:

> [image]

Знаки слетели и на Мете и на основном.
Еще тут:

> [image]

Comment: По-моему, пора уже канонический вопрос создать со ссылками на MSE. И закрывать все эти странные слёты переведов на него.

Comment: Знаки уже на месте, кстати. Да и текст по очередям тоже.

Comment: Что ж за беда такая, что постоянно слетает?